# How to explicitly define grid's grid-template-rows to be dependent on each other's height

Tags: html, css

I have some headache picking correct value for `grid-template-rows` property in grid layout. My requirement is if row is empty and other row has no content or content height is higher than 50px then set row height to 50px; If other row's content is smaller than 50px then set row's content to same height as other's row. If row has own content then height should be content height. Please see example code below with possible scenarios.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior only by `grid-template-rows` property (using `minmax`, `fr` units or other options)?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.grid-container>div:nth-child(1) {
  background: lime;
}

.row1 {
  height: 50px;
}

.row2 {
  height: 100px;
}

.row3 {
  height: 30px;
}

.row4 {
  height: 30px;
}

.row5 {
  height: 25px;
}

.row6 {
  height: 40px;
}

.row7 {
  height: 50px;
}

.row8 {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row1">
    I am empty row my height is 50px as other row content is higher than 50px;
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    My content height is 100px;
  </div>

</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row3">
    I am empty row my height is 30px because other row content is smaller than 50px and is 30px;
  </div>
  <div class="row4">
    My content height is 30px;
  </div>

</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row5">
    I have content of height 25px so I am 25px in height, so other row height doesn't matter;
  </div>
  <div class="row6">
    I have content of 40px;
  </div>

</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row7">
    I am empty and other row empty so we both 50px;
  </div>
  <div class="row8">
    I am empty and other row empty so we both 50px;
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question that actually matches what's in your post.

Comment: "I am empty"? What does it mean for a row to be "empty"? To me (and CSS's `:empty` pseudo-class), it means there are absolutely no child nodes (meaning no child text nodes, including white space text nodes).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, what I mean is when you define explicity grid-templare-rows: 100px 100px, then there will be two grid rows no matter if grid has any content or it is empty div. I want to add children to grid dynamically so sometimes there can be empty div grid tag, but two rows should be present with minimum heights

Comment: ... and I'm asking you to define "empty". Because you could use [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) to define different `grid-template-rows`, but if you consider a div with just a little text in it to be "empty", then that won't work.